# Webpack 2 Minimize - LoaderOptionsPlugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

How can I minimize my bundle output file. I try with this configuration: [link](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/loader-options-plugin/#examples)

```
new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
  minimize: true,
  debug: false,
  options: {
    context: __dirname
  }
})
```

But my bundle file stay same size as it was.

Comment: I have the same. Did you sove this issue ?

Comment: Look my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and it worked.
First I add `UglifyJsPlugin` in `webpack` configuration:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: { warnings: false }
})
```

Problem was that I didn't have all babel packages installed:

```
"babel": "^6.23.0",
"babel-core": "^6.23.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.3.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
"babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.22.0",
"babel-register": "^6.22.0",
```

And in `.babelrc` file configuration:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-3"],
    "compact" : false
}
```

Hope it will help to somebody.